# Functions of adding `this` to methods & static and instance methods [Java]

Tags: java, methods, static, instance

For one of my programming assignments, I was tasked to write a couple methods. I noticed that one of my methods could be expressed as using an if-else statement between two methods I already defined. I cannot change the method signatures to make those two other methods static.

I heard somewhere/was briefly taught that you can add `this` in front of the method (`this.method()`). Does that change it so that instance methods could be use statically? What does adding `this` specifically do? Is it "good practice" to use it like this?

Pseudocode for two methods:

```
public boolean methodA(input){
    //does something
    return true or false depending on something;
}
public boolean methodB(input){
    //does something else
    return true or false depending on something else;
}
```

I noticed after coding that I can call the methods inside each other without using `this` so my question really is, which is better/more reliable? Using `this` vs. not using `this`???

```
public boolean methodAB(input){
    boolean present = input is already present;
    if(present) {return methodA();}
    else {return methodB();}
}
```

or...

```
public boolean methodAB(input){
    boolean present = input is already present;
    if(present) {return this.methodA();}
    else {return this.methodB();}
}
```

Comment: " Does that change it so that instance methods could be use statically?" No.  "What does adding this specifically do?" Nothing; it's fully equivalent to use it or to leave it out.  "Is it "good practice" to use it like this?" No.